# How to close/hide the current conversation?

Tags: windows, skype, web-application

When the Skype application (either on Windows or using the web app), it shows a split screen where the recent chats are listed on the left and a welcome screen on the right (essentially, an empty conversation pane). Whenever a conversation is open, it gets displayed to the right, in place of the welcome screen.

All that is fine. However, when I'm done chatting, there doesn't seem to be a way to close/hide the current conversation and return to the home/welcome screen. Most chat apps have a close/back button and/or a keyboard shortcut (e.g., <kbd>Esc</kbd>) for this purpose. On Skype, it seems that once a chat is open, I'm stuck with having a conversation open at all times. Even if I close skype (which minimizes it to tray), it still shows the conversation when I reopen it. It does, however, go to the home page if I completely exit the program and relaunch it. This is not a real solution though.

The same problem exists on the web app (i.e., no close button or shortcut), but with the web version, at least, refreshing the page forces it to open the welcome page.

Is there any way to close/hide the current conversation without exiting Skype completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the newer versions of Skype<sup>*</sup> don't seem to have an official way to close the chat on PC unless the "split view mode" is enabled (which is really poorly named because it actually opens the chat in a separate window).

However, both they seem to have designed those newer versions in a responsive way so that the app can adapt itself to work on mobile. Fortunately, they had to add a "back" button for the "mobile view" because that's the only way to access the "Recent chats" list. So, until Skype decides to fix this for the "desktop mode", a workaround is to resize the window by decreasing its width until it switches to the the "mobile view" where the "back" button can be presses.

This works on both the Windows and the web version but it's probably more useful on Windows because refreshing the page seems easier on a browser. Here are the two views (click on the image to view in full size):

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Skype 7 used to have a "Home" button.</sub>